# MySQL: Optimising a query involving calculations

Tags: mysql, optimization

How can I optimise a query that uses the same calculation for `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`?

For example:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM my_table
WHERE    SIN(a) + COS(b) + TAN(5.5) < 10
ORDER BY SIN(a) + COS(b) + TAN(5.5)
```

`5.5` and `10` in this example are user-supplied values that will change between queries. This is a simplification -- the actual calculation is relatively complex, so it is not possible to store the result in another column.

Due to an application limitation, I cannot add the calculation to the `SELECT` statement. How do I prevent MySQL from having to perform the same calculation twice per row?

Finally, should I be using `WHERE` or `HAVING` to filter by the result of a calculation?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have my development machine in front of me, does this work?

```
SELECT a, b
FROM my_table
ORDER BY ( SIN(a) + COS(b) + TAN(5.5) )
HAVING   ( SIN(a) + COS(b) + TAN(5.5) ) < 10
```

If it does the HAVING statement shouldn't be recalculating the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by storing a calculated column, which is updated via a trigger.  The downsides are that it would take up some extra space, and it would slow down inserts and updates.  However, depending on your specific situation, I may even be faster.  It also depends on how many calculations you man need.  Do you need cos,sin,tan values for all of a,b,c for various other things in your database, or do you just need sin(a), cos(b), and tan(c).  Maybe you can even get away with storing the final result of SIN(a) + COS(b) + TAN(c).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I may have over-simplified the situation a little, so I have just updated my example. The `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` perform a calculation based on a combination of column values and input values. The input values will change per query, so it will not be possible to store the calculated value.

Comment: Even then, you'd only have to store sin(a) and cos(b).  TAN(5.5)  and 10 are already constant, and shouldn't be caculated more than once by the database, if TAN(5.5) is, you can calculate the a value in your program, before sending it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT a, b from (
   SELECT a, b, SIN(a) + COS(b) + TAN(5.5) as filter
   FROM my_table
) as tmp1
WHERE  filter < 10
ORDER BY filter
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, but @Matt Wilson's answer performed more quickly.

Comment: nice to know that, because it is suposed that `where` and `having` are equivalent on a query without `group by`